# Replace text starting with space using AutoCorrect

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, autocorrect

How to I replace the following text with another text string?

```
"<space> QWERTY" → "qwerty"
```

The string that is going to be replaced starts with a space. Actually a hard space. It seems like I can't replace a text string starting with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved this by inserting a dot:

Replace:

```
.QWERTY
```

with:

```
qwerty
```

This may come in handy in Word when frequently using m³, °C, etc:

```
1337.m3 → 1337 m³
```

Answer (score 0):

All that you should need to do is use `CTRL+H` to open the "Find and Replace" dialogue box and then enter `QWERTY` (with the space) in the "Find What:" field and `querty` in the "Replace with" field. and hit the "Replace All" button.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution not involving search and replace. Any ideas?

Comment: Doing it completely automatically - I'm not sure, however, there is a semi-automatic way to do it. There's a piece of software called AutoHotKey (https://autohotkey.com/download/) that allows you to set up a keyboard short-cuts including, if I am not mistaken, Ctrl-key combinations, so that you can use (for example) `Ctrl+Win+Z` to initiate the sequence of key strokes to automatically do the `Ctrl+H` and then enter the text to be replaced and the replacement text as well as press replace all. I've not used AutoHotKey personally, but I believe it is possible.